# mongoose async callback undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I use 'mongoose' and 'async'. My search also works, but at the last callback my data will not be passed. The variable is always undefined. In the documentation of mongoose I have not found clue. I've marked the mentioned Location in the Code.

```
async.whilst(
    function() {
      return noresult
    },
    function(callback) {
      if (day >= 7 && newdate >= 1440) {
        noresult = false;
        callback("Nothing", newquery);

      } else if (day < 7 && newdate >= 1440) {
        day++;
        newdate = 0;
        delete newquery['search.'
            ' + d[day- 1]];
            delete newquery['search.
              ' + d[day - 1] + '
              b '];
              newquery['search.' + d[day]] = {
                $lte: newdate
              }; newquery['search.' + d[day] + 'b'] = {
                $gte: newdate
              }; console.log("1 " + day + " " + newdate);
            } else if (day >= 7 && newdate < 1440) {
              newdate++;
              console.log("2 " + day + " " + newdate);
            } else if (day <= 7 && newdate < 1440) {
              newdate++;
              delete newquery['search.' + d[day - 1]];
              delete newquery['search.' + d[day - 1] + 'b'];
              newquery['search.' + d[day]] = {
                $lte: newdate
              };
              newquery['search.' + d[day] + 'b'] = {
                $gte: newdate
              };
            }

            Data.find(newquery, function(err, newresult) {
              if (err) {
                callback(err);
              }
              if (!newresult.length) {
                noresult = true;
                if (day >= 7 && newdate >= 1440) {
                  callback("Nothing found");
                } else {
                  callback(null, newquery);
                }
              } else {
                noresult = false;
                callback(null, newresult);
              }
            });


          },
          function(err, newresult) {
            if (err) {
              return res.status(404).send(err);
            }
            // At this point newresult is undefined
            return res.send(newresult);

          }
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the implementation of that [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst) function and it doesn't produce last result to the final callback. So it's probably some misleading to the documentation.

I've implemented my own whilst which does what you need:

```
var whilst = function (test, iterator, callback, prevResult) { 
    if (test()) { 
        iterator(function (err, result) { 
            if (err) { 
                return callback(err); 
            } 
            whilst(test, iterator, callback, result); 
        }); 
    } 
    else { 
        callback(null, prevResult); 
    } 
};
```

Try to use it instead of async.whilst. Let me know whether it worked for you.

Update:

As I find out there is actually an [issue](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/967) about this misleading so it will be fixed in the newer version of async library.

Comment: I understand the code, but have no idea how to use this in my example. The async has an error is very unfortunate.

Comment: @Jack Instead of using async.whilst function just declare and use our whilst function. The rest of your code remains the same. If you want you can actually expand async object with our whilst function using lodash mixin.

Comment: I know, but I do not get it to run.

Comment: Can you help me or create a Little example on JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/5gvfg37h/ . Let me know if you have some question about it.